# RMarkdown citations highlighting in other themes than Textmate

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

A quick question: in the standard Rstudio "Textmate" theme, markdown citations (the square brackets followed by @ i.e, [@Judge2001] are highlighted. I have no found no other theme (dark or bright) that does that.

Q: How can I edit the themes so that I can see the citations in other colors within Rmarkdown text?

Comment: Try this https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/10/29/rstudio-ide-custom-theme-support/

Answer (score 4):

You can add:

```
.ace_list, .ace_markup.ace_list, .ace_storage {
color: #66db80;
  }
```

to any .rstheme file you want and choose the color of your preference to highlight citation keys.

Comment: This is great! I know this is an old comment but do you have a source I can reference for further changes? I want to set a color for cross references inside the mardown document (e.g. \@ref(fig:model-selection) and I would like to check what are all the fields that can be edited this way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Diego's response, the selectors `.ace_list .ace_markup` did it for me. (Perhaps it was just a typo.) They are the classes used in the <span> around citations when you look at them in 'Inspect element'.

```
.ace_list, .ace_markup {
   color: #66db80;
}
```

(I would've posted this as a comment, but apparently I'm too disreputable.)